# Read Excel file using Java with Property file

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read an Excel file using Java.
I did this successfully by using `org.apache.poi` which is returning all of the data column wise.

But now I want to read the same excel file by column names only which will be given by the user. The twisting part is that I want to accept column names from a property file and only those names, which are in the property file, those column's data should be shown by the program. So any suggestions? How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

use net.sf.supercsv library for reading EXL file by header/column name